# Script editor working only in edit page mode

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When in edit page mode the script works, but when I stop editing the page the script will not run.

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function FilterOMenu(c, a) {
    //Be carefull with overriding SharePoint core functions, for now this will work (September 2016 CU). Ensure you test this every time after installing a SharePoint update.
    //SharePoint default (I placed this above, cause it returns.)
    if (a == null)
        return;
    var b = a.tagName == "DIV" ? a.parentNode : a;
    //End SharePoint default

    //Custom implementation to sort the filter
    var fieldInternalName = a.getAttribute("name");

    //some sort functions
    var ascComparer = function(a,b){return a.text<b.text ? -1:a.text>b.text ? 1 : 0;};
    var descComparer = function(a,b){return a.text>b.text ? -1:a.text<b.text ? 1 : 0;};
    var ascDateComparer = function(a,b){d1 = Date.parse(a.text);d2 = Date.parse(b.text);return d1<d2 ? -1:d1>d2 ? 1 : 0;};
    var descDateComparer = function(a,b){d1 = Date.parse(a.text);d2 = Date.parse(b.text);return d1>d2 ? -1:d1<d2 ? 1 : 0;};

    var myCustomSort = {};
    //Add the field internal name and give a comparer as value to sort
    //As example the title column as your case is
    myCustomSort["Kuup_x00e4_ev"] = descDateComparer;
    //myCustomSort["Aktiivne"] = ascComparer;
    //console.log(myCustomSort["Date"]);

    if(typeof c != "undefined" && c != null && typeof myCustomSort[fieldInternalName] != "undefined"){//check if you implemented a custom sort for the current internalname
        //select all items that are checkable (the options)
        var allSelectableItems = c.querySelectorAll('[checked]');
        if(allSelectableItems.length > 0){
            var elementInnerhtmls = [];
            var htmlToReplace = "";
            var htmlToAppend = "";
            for(var i = 0;i<allSelectableItems.length;i++)
            {
                elementInnerhtmls.push({text: allSelectableItems[i].getAttribute("text"),html:allSelectableItems[i].outerHTML});
                htmlToReplace += allSelectableItems[i].outerHTML; 
            }
            elementInnerhtmls = elementInnerhtmls.sort(myCustomSort[fieldInternalName]);
            for(var i = 0;i<elementInnerhtmls.length;i++)
            {
                htmlToAppend += elementInnerhtmls[i].html;
            }
            //replace the original html with the sorted html
            c.innerHTML = c.innerHTML.replace(htmlToReplace,htmlToAppend);
        }
    }
    //SharePoint default
    OMenu(c, b, null, null, -1)
    //End SharePoint default
} </script>
```

I have the language and type attributes set, but still nothing.
Can someone tell me why my publishing page script only runs when I go to edit the page?

Comment: If you try to add a simple JavaScript alert in your Script Editor Webpart, like alert('test'), does it work or not ?

Comment: @SylvainB Simple alert works. I added an alert before the function starts and right after the function starts. And the one inside the function will not pop.

Comment: what is omenu code look like...the function name you are calling doesnt match the function defined

Answer (score 0):

**This issue usually occurs in case of the following:**

- The Script tag doesn’t have `type=”text/javascript”`.
- The `“SP.js”` and `“SP.Runtime”` files are not refrenced properly.
- You didn’t call the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` function.
- The `Minimal Download Strategy Feature` is activated.
- The code is not written correctly!

For more details, check [SharePoint 2016: JSOM is only working in Edit Mode](https://itcore.devoworx.net/jsom-is-only-working-in-edit-mode/)